# Why should I use a service principal for machine authentication and not an AAD user?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I know that I have to create a service principal when I need an identity for an app that connects to Azure resources. But if someone asked me "Why not just create an AAD user and authenticate as that user?" I honestly couldn't answer besides "That's not how you do it.".

Can someone give me a proper explanation on why using an AAD service user instead of an app registration would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service principal** is an application whose tokens can be used to authenticate and grant access to specific Azure resources from a user-app, service, or automation tool, when an organization is using Azure Active Directory

By using a Service Principal, we can avoid creating "fake users" (similar to service account in on-premises Active Directory) in Azure AD to manage authentication when you need to access Azure Resources

The Service Principals' access can be restricted by assigning Azure RBAC roles so that they can access the specific set of Azure resources only

So for better security purpose, we can use service principal instead of Azure AD User from an to authenticate and access Azure Resources.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.